# How to get all the network names of a VM using powershell

Tags: powershell

Am new to powershell.I have to get the names of all network a VM can connect to.So, please can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

If your using Hyper-V you can try to install PowerShell Management Library for Hyper-V
http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/
Or you have to find a WMI you can use
Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapter

Answer (score 1):

In [PowerCLI](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/index.html), you can use the Get-VirtualPortGroup  command:

```
Get-VirtualPortGroup ESXi.FQDN.local
Name                           Key                            VirtualSwitch   VLanId
----                           ---                            -------------   ------
VM Network                     key-vim.host.PortGroup-VM N... vSwitch0        0
Management Network             key-vim.host.PortGroup-Mana... vSwitch0        0
```